# Is it possible to extract classes probabilities assigned to training images from a saved CNN?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save, hdf5

I trained a CNN to perform a classification task, I used `vgg16` with `categorical_crossentropy` loss function, `sgd` optimizer, and `softmax` activation function.

I saved then the trained model to h5 file.
I know that the function to get classes probabilities vector for a new unseen image is `predict`.

1. But, what I want to know is whether the final classes probabilities assigned to training images are saved with the model?
2. If yes, how can I extract this information from the saved model without the need of using `predict` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `HDF5 (.h5, .hdf5)` is a file format suitable for storing large
>   collections of multidimensional numeric arrays (e.g. models, data
>   files).

1. yes you could save the *"final classes probabilities assigned to training images"*   during your Training into an `.h5` file.
2. But since you only *"saved then the trained model to `.h5` file"* there will be only the network model (with its weights, architecture and the optimizer configuration if you defined so) in this file (more Information can be found [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models) - section "As an HDF5 file").

From here your easiest option, is what you already mentioned: *"Extract this information from the saved model **with**[out] the need of using predict function"*.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Anyway, classes probabilities are exactly the same in both cases? (Since the neural network configuration is the same).

Comment: So I would say similar. Since even in your last Training epoch, the weights will be changing due to your updates, consecutively the probabilites will become different too (though usually not too much, since you model should have converged pretty well at that Point).